# having String Index Out Of Bounds Exception while file reading

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

```
public List<SoruKelime> getAllQuestion() {
        List<SoruKelime> questions = new ArrayList<>();
        try { 
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myFile);

            while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                String data;
                data = myReader.nextLine();
                int index = data.indexOf("&");
                String question = data.substring(0, index);
                String answer = data.substring(index+1);
                SoruKelime soru = new SoruKelime();
                soru.setSoru(question);
                soru.setKelime(answer);
                questions.add(soru);
            }
            myReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return questions;
    }


  @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        FileProcess fileProcess = new FileProcess();
        List<SoruKelime> sorular = new LinkedList<SoruKelime>();
        SoruKelime cekilenSoru = new SoruKelime();
        sorular = (ArrayList<SoruKelime>) fileProcess.getAllQuestion();
        cekilenSoru = sorular.get(0);

        this.soruLabel.setText(cekilenSoru.getSoru());
    
    }    


Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
    at word_game.FileProcess.getAllQuestion(FileProcess.java:53)
    at word_game.GameController.initialize(GameController.java:34)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
```

while i'm reading a file in java with javafx i'm having this kind of issue. i've tried to change linkedList to List but that didn't work. I don't know what else I can do. Can you help me about that

Comment: Post a sample of your file content.

Comment: Is the ampersand ever at the end of the line?

Comment: 1- Ulvi sözünün Türkçe sağlanan eş anlamlısı? & yüce ( there is14 more lines like this)

Comment: I can't find this error

Comment: `at word_game.FileProcess.getAllQuestion(FileProcess.java:53)` What line is this?

Comment: Also, this question has no relationship to `JavaFX`. This is a basic `Java` issue.

Comment: I want to read the data in the file and write to a label

Comment: String question = data.substring(0, index);  it is this line

Comment: java naming conventions please

Answer (score 0):

You might have a line where there isn't an ampersand (&).
Now, it is always a nice practice to assure yourself that what you're going to access exists, so you won't end up with NullPointers or IndexOutOfBounds.

```
        List<SoruKelime> questions = new ArrayList<>();
        try { 
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myFile);

            while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                String data;
                data = myReader.nextLine();
                int index = data.indexOf('&');
                if(index==-1 || index > data.length){
                   //There is no &, do something
                }else{
                   String question = data.substring(0, index);
                   String answer = data.substring(index+1);
                   SoruKelime soru = new SoruKelime();
                   soru.setSoru(question);
                   soru.setKelime(answer);
                   questions.add(soru);
                 }
            }
            myReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return questions;
    }
```

Comment: 1- Ulvi sözünün Türkçe sağlanan eş anlamlısı? & yüce
2- Deride sinirler boyunca beliren, “Gece yanığı” olarak da bilinen hastalık & zona
3-Gelişen teknolojiyle birçok insanın dalabileceği düşünülen elektromekanik araç? & robot
my file content is like this

Comment: @dionyysuss I edited the ```indexOf('&')```. I am not sure why it didn't give you a warning at compiling because "&" is a string but '&' is a character. Use '&'.